# Something doesn't feel right about how I am dynamically populating an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

**Here is my object hierarchy:**
`NSWindowController` owns a `NSViewController`, which is the `Data Source` & `Delegate` for my `NSTableView`.

`NSWindowController` fetches some data from the internet, and passes this to the `NSViewController` so that it can populate the `NSTableView`.  This happens asynchronously, so the `NSTableView` is initially loaded with 0 rows.

`NSViewController` owns the `NSTableView`, as well as an `NSArray` (as the `Data Source`).  Both of these properties are private.

**From here I'm not confident in my implementation:**
Once the `NSWindowController` has finished fetching the data, I call a public method on the `NSViewController` which I named `-addStringToArray:(NSString*)` (to avoid making the array public and then just directly calling `-addObject` on the `NSArray`).  `-addStringToArray` just then calls `-addObject` on the private `NSArray`, and **also** calls `[self.tableView reloadData]`.  This call at this location is where I'm mostly sketched out (Though I will gladly take any input on any part of my solution here)

Because when the `NSTableView` is loaded, it has 0 rows, when the `Data Source` (`NSViewController`) method `-numberOfRowsInTableView` gets called, it returns 0.  This in turn makes it so the `Delegate` method `-viewForTableColumn...` just never gets called, because (I'm assuming) it thinks there are 0 rows.

To get this method to get called, I need to call the `NSTableView`'s `-reloadData`.

**TL;DR**:
Table gets loaded with 0 rows.
Add strings to an array.
Every time a string is added call `reloadData`.
This calls `-numberOfRowsInTableView`, which returns the size of the array.
This also allows `-viewForTableColumn...` to be called, which then returns the appropriate string which then populates the table.

Am I dynamically adding items into my NSTableView in the best way possible?

Comment: Doesn't sound out of line for an implementation without bindings.  You could try `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` though I'm not sure how it works if the rowIndices are not yet present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Assuming you're targeting deployment to 10.7 or later, you can use `-[NSTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:withAnimation:]` after changing your data model. That avoids the full reload of data.